# Inherited platform declarations clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (processAllModels(Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/util/Map;):

Tags: java, kotlin

```
 The following declarations have the same JVM signature (postProcessAllModels(Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/util/Map;):
    [javac]     fun postProcessAllModels(objs: MutableMap<String?, Any?>?): MutableMap<String?, Any?>? defined in CheckCodegen
    [javac]     fun postProcessAllModels(p0: MutableMap<String?, ModelsMap?>?): MutableMap<String?, ModelsMap?>? defined in CheckCodegen
    [javac] class PayStationControllerCodegen(codegenAmender: CodegenAmender = combinedAmender())
    [javac]       ^
```

in CheckCodegen:

```kotlin
class CheckCodegen(codegenAmender: CodegenAmender = combinedAmender())
    : AbstractCheckCodegen(codegenAmender)

    private fun combinedAmender() = CodegenAmender.combine(
        PolymorphicPropertyTyper(),
        ModelSpecializer(), ......)
```

In AbstractCheckCodegen [Java]

```java
public AbstractCheckCodegen(CodegenAmender codegenAmender) {
    this(codegenAmender, getPrivateFieldsSystemProperty());
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Map<String, Object> processAllModels(Map<String, Object> objs) {
    List<CodegenModel> models = objs.values().stream()
            .map(value -> (Map<String, Object>) value)
            .flatMap(inner -> ((List<Map<String, Object>>) inner.get("models")).stream())
            .map(mo -> (CodegenModel) mo.get("model"))
            .collect(ImmutableList.toImmutableList());

    models.forEach(codegenAmender::amendModel);
    codegenAmender.amendModels(models);

    return super.processAllModels(objs);
}
```

I tried adding:

```kotlin
@JvmName("setcombinedAmender")
private fun combinedAmender() = CodegenAmender.combine(
```

but it did not work